# Adding controllable noise to VQE to find ground state energy

Tags: qiskit, vqe, noise

I am wanting to add noise to my code which uses VQE to find ground state energy for LiH at various inter atomic distances. The code I am wanting to add to is the code found from the qiskit text book. https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html under "running VQE on a statevector simulator"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can't add noise to the statevector simulator. You'll have to follow the code in the section below where they create a noisy simulator by coupling a noise model to Aer's qasm simulator.

Comment: You can find another example of adding a noise model in Qiskit in the answer here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/28402/12855